# Flag for Google Crawlers When Using Geolocation getCurrentPosition

Tags: html, angular, google-crawlers, google-search-console

I am trying to get a page indexed by google, however, the google crawlers don't seem to ever get a response (success or error) from the [html5 geolocation getCurrentPosition method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition). When I use the Google Search Console to "fetch and render" the page, all I see is my loading gif that is supposed to be hidden once the callback method is invoked. But because the callback never happens, all I see is the loader.

The page is coded in Angular, so google usually has no problem rendering the contents of the page from the JavaScript, unless of course I am using the geolocation stuff.

Here are my questions:

1. Why won't the geolocation getCurrentPosition method work when a googlebot crawls my page?
2. Is there a flag I can use to divert the crawlers to using a hardcoded geolocation instead? Ex:

   ```
   if(isCrawler){ // The flag would go here.
       this.getLocalEntities(0, 0); // Hardcoded
       return;
   }
   // else, use Geolocation service:
   this.geoLocationService.getLocation({enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 50000, maximumAge: Infinity }).subscribe(
       position=>{
           console.log('POSITION', position);
           this.getLocalEntities(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
       },
       error=> {
           console.log('ERROR', error);
           this.getLocalEntities(0, 0);
       }
   );
   ```

I'm open to suggestions. Thanks :)

Comment: I thought the google crawler might be rendering the content from a server, in which case the `window` object wouldn't be defined, so I tried using `!window` as the flag but that did not work :(

Comment: What about using a polyfill for the html5 geoLocation service? Would that work?